# Timestamp before now?

Tags: php, mysql

Quite simply, I have the following query

```
$q = "SELECT fixture_date FROM ".TBL_FOOT_GAMES." WHERE leagueid = '$league_id' AND (type = '2' OR type = '12' OR type = '22' OR type = '32') GROUP BY fixture_date ORDER BY fixture_date";
```

I need to add a `WHERE` on `fixture_date` which is a timestamp. The where needs to be before the current moment in time.

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE fixture_date < NOW();
```

That what you're going for? timestamps can be compared like any other data type.

Comment: That should work yet it's still showing all the fixtures, not just the ones before now...hmmm. Must be something in my code!

Answer (score 1):

WHERE fixture_date < NOW();
That should do it :)